# SQLAlchemy session is invalidated unexpectedly causing PendingRollbackError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using SQLAlchemy (2.0.20) as an ORM library in my FastAPI project.
Whenever a request is made to the API server, the route requires a db `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session` object.
This session object is either created anew by a `DbSession = sessionmaker(engine)` or taken from the cache

```
engine = create_engine(
    connection_string(),
    poolclass=QueuePool,
    pool_size=15,
    pool_recycle=3600,
)
DbSession = sessionmaker(engine)

@cache
def get_db_session() -> Session:
    session = DbSession()
    return session  # this is then used in the fastapi route
```

At some point, the API does not function anymore because this cached session object is [invalidated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#more-on-invalidation) (for unknown reason) and I get the error
"PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back" [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/errors.html#can-t-reconnect-until-invalid-transaction-is-rolled-back-please-rollback-fully-before-proceeding) whenever I want to use the session.

```
class SqlRepository:  # this repository object is also cached across API requests (like the session)
   def __init__(session: Session):
       self.session = session

   def get_all_todos(self):
       self.session.query(TodoORM).all()  # this is where the PendingRollbackError is thrown
       ...
```

So my questions are

- should I re-create the session for every API request (i.e. not cache it)?
- should I handle the `PendingRollbackError` in `get_all_todos`?

My intention behind caching the session was that I have a long-lived session that only has to be instantiated once that uses connections from the connection pool. Is the pattern correct to instantiate a repository with the session object or should it rather have access to the sessionmaker and re-create sessions everytime a db transaction must be made.

Comment: Yes, you should recreate the session for every API request. It's covered in the SQLAlchemy docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it - "Web applications. In this case, it’s best to make use of the SQLAlchemy integrations provided by the web framework in use. Or otherwise, the basic pattern is create a Session at the start of a web request, call the Session.commit() method at the end of web requests that do POST, PUT, or DELETE, and then close the session at the end of web request. "

Comment: Use pooling for connections, keep sessions request specific.